# Load local data infile from a file to multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

name ( name , sex )
job (job , name )

I want insert into these tables from a text file. The data for both tables is in one file
separated by a line '#':

```
ony,male
galih,female
#
teacher,galih
worker,ony
```

(Data of table name before the #, data of table job after the #)

I want to do this in two steps:

```
load data local infile 'test.txt'
into table name
lines terminated before line #
```

Then:

```
load data local infile 'test.txt'
into table job
lines starting after line #
```

Is there any way to make the script or use other means to load a txt file containing data for multiple tables with a line separator # ?

Comment: If possible it would be good for you to give us your table structures,that you currently have

Comment: Yes , like that Jan Doggen , sory it my first time ask to this forum , like confuse .. tq..

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the data into the format of something like

```
(name,sex)
```

You could create one large insert statement like

```
INSERT INTO TableName (name,sex) VALUES
('Mr Smith','Male'),('Mrs Smith','Female'),('Mr Wright','Male');
```

How from your question it isn't clear if there is any relationship between the two tables ?  Because if their is you'd need to reference a primary key when inserting the data and this could be a problem.

Comment: Tq Tommo 1977 , theres no relation from two tables , just example . sorry my english is not good , i want to load data from test.txt to table name , which data is before line #

Comment: Somethings like load data local infile 'test.txt' into table name fields terminated by ',' lines stop before #